# In Scala or Java, how to get how much RAM does application currently occupy?

Tags: java, memory, scala, jvm, jmx

NetBeans IDE has a taskbar indicaror, showing how much RAM is currently allocated and used by the running instance. How can I get this data in my own application written in Scala? If there's no special function for this in Scala, I could use Java one.

Comment: Telling how much of the java heap is used is easy.  Telling how much memory is exclusively used by this process is a lot more tricky.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
private val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
import runtime.{ totalMemory, freeMemory, maxMemory }

 System.out.println("New session, \ 
    total memory = %s, max memory = %s, free memory = %s".format(
        totalMemory, maxMemory, freeMemory))
```

Just copied from [http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/CompileServer.scala.html](http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/CompileServer.scala.html#130971)

Answer (score 3):

You can either use the [totalMemory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory()) and [maxMemory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory()) methods from the java.lang.Runtime class, or make use of the [MemoryMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html).